# print the lines where two consecutive words never share the same character , uesing grep

Tags: grep

i have input like this

```
sie%Qu7s Kuux"oh9 ohc9ahG% hoe8Toh: Eix*ohd1 doh:bo2U Cu0doo|t zo`L9xaW
5ciw3GRd 2sYpKD:T x0OU7Irq #V5ueAF6 7aH;cJOo 1n8(tQwI ivopx2y0 ,69tGqR4
fie5Du[h Phe8aid# Opu&fai5 ieZ<aek6 hu4ga&Di Oose}p1o aiD@oos2 nu-a1Fub
ahqu5To/ ahtie[H3 ioK&u5Ai nei1Za#d poo_Th9r gu|aGh7h uZ%io2ah IeNah&v7
```

where each word in the column constitutes a password

i am trying to print the lines where two consecutive passwords never share the same character , uesing `grep` command

```
grep -v ' .*\(.\).* .*\1.* ' file.name
```

expected output

```
5ciw3GRd 2sYpKD:T x0OU7Irq #V5ueAF6 7aH;cJOo 1n8(tQwI ivopx2y0 ,69tGqR4
```

someone can help ?

Comment: Homework? Very similar question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/69690750/3776858

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More like:

```
$ grep -v '\([^ ]\)[^ ]* [^ ]*\1' file
5ciw3GRd 2sYpKD:T x0OU7Irq #V5ueAF6 7aH;cJOo 1n8(tQwI ivopx2y0 ,69tGqR4
```