# print lines where each word contains two same characters in Linux

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have input like this

```
LTCYMM SVNNDA DTVEV QLOPGO CUPUR
MMWVJM LIVLI WBSVD UQCMW HBMDA HVVFY BWYSS
NOGWOS JIKKDI GCIQAD MXJNWE SMVFCB GIZVPA GZOHZR WJBMZS
KKPQBP BKDKRU ZTPDPL ZRLUEL HRZZKO KXSKCU YZQTBT RISNKS
VYQQC BFAWI NSZDV HKPGI KVJOC COPPS
JGU YLN MXW ACR BZA HOP
TMCVPT HBNGIH IQYGCI DTQPON WXANKG GMIYZS
CWVT BUBA NSGR MUPO LDNS
```

i am trying to print  lines where each word contains **at leats  two same characters**,
useing grep `command`
The longest line contains 8 words  ، I think I can solve it like that ،but i feel that is the wrong way ,

```
grep '^.*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\1[^ ]* [^ ]*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\2[^ ]*   [^ ]*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\3[^ ]* [^ ]*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\4[^ ]* [^ ]*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\5[^ ]* [^ ]*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\6[^ ]* [^ ]*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\7[^ ]* [^ ]*\([A-Z]\)[^ ]*\8[^ ]*$/| .... for 7 words | for 6 ...
```

expected output

```
 LTCYMM SVNNDA DTVEV QLOPGO CUPUR
 KKPQBP BKDKRU ZTPDPL ZRLUEL HRZZKO KXSKCU YZQTBT RISNKS
```

Comment: What is the expected output? What do you mean by "where each word contains at least two of the characters? Two characters anywhere in the string?  Consecutively

Comment: I edited the question ، Each word is separate from the other by space , each word must have at least two similar letters

Comment: how is the answer different to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/674535/print-the-lines-where-two-consecutive-words-never-share-the-same-character-ues

Comment: i didn't get you ! it is totally different

Comment: The relevant techniques are identical. If you had analysed and understood the previous answers properly, you would have learned how to deal with a whole class of such problems. Instead, you appear to be intent on just having your homework done for free.

Comment: Instead of making yourself a teacher, you can give me some details to follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `perl`:

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless grep {!/(.).*\1/} /\S+/g' file
LTCYMM SVNNDA DTVEV QLOPGO CUPUR
KKPQBP BKDKRU ZTPDPL ZRLUEL HRZZKO KXSKCU YZQTBT RISNKS
```

Or with `grep` implementations with support for perl-like regexps:

```
$ grep -Pve '(?<!\S)(?!\S*(\S)\S*\1)\S' file
LTCYMM SVNNDA DTVEV QLOPGO CUPUR
KKPQBP BKDKRU ZTPDPL ZRLUEL HRZZKO KXSKCU YZQTBT RISNKS
```

That prints the lines that do *not* (with `-v`) contain a `\S` (non-whitespace character) that is not preceded by another non-whitespace (`(?<!\S)`) (or IOW that is the start of a white-space delimited word) and is not the start of a sequence of non-whitespaces one of which is repeated (`(?!\S*(\S)\S*\1)`). So in essence similar to (though less legible than) the `perl` approach above.

Note that they also print blank lines (as they don't contain words that don't have repeated characters). If you don't want them, you can exclude them which should be trivial (such as by adding a `-e '^\s*$'` in the `grep` one).

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
awk '{
    for ( fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++ ) {
        numChars = length($fldNr)
        numUnq = 0
        split("",seen)       # you could use delete(seen) here in most awks
        for ( charNr=1; charNr<=numChars; charNr++ ) {
            if ( !seen[substr($fldNr,charNr,1)]++ ) {
                numUnq++
            }
        }
        if ( numUnq == numChars ) {
            next
        }
    }
    print 
}' file
LTCYMM SVNNDA DTVEV QLOPGO CUPUR
KKPQBP BKDKRU ZTPDPL ZRLUEL HRZZKO KXSKCU YZQTBT RISNKS
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` along with the `all` method from the `List::Util` module we can detect the desired lines (all words with atleast one duplicated charadter)

```
perl -MList::Util=all  -lane '
  print if all { /(.).*\1/ } @F;
' file
```

---

Using the `GnU sed` we can select the desired lines when we ensure all desired fields stretch from the beginning of line to end.

```
$ sed -En '/^\s*(\S*(\S)\S*\2\S*(\s+|$))+$/p' file
```

---

Another way with `sed` is to progressively check for a duplicated char amongst the nonwhitespace characters
and don't print the pattern space as soon as no duplicates are found in a nonwhitespace run of characters.

```
sed -Ee 'h
  :loop
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g
    s/\S+/&\n/
    /(\S).*\1.*\n/!d
    s/^[^\n]*\n//
  /./bloop
  g
' file
```

---

We utilize awk and then loop over every word and every char in a word. Split word over the char and check if it breaks into more than 2 parts => dup detected in this word. Like wise at the end of current line if count of dups detected equals the number of fields => line fit to print.

```
awk '
{
  for (p=i=1+(w=0); i<=NF; i++) {
    while (p <= length($i)) {
      c = substr($i,p++,1)
      if (split($i,a,c) > 2) {
        w += p = 1
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
w==NF
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another solution in pure Bash — no `perl`, no `grep`, no `awk`.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

containssametwice() {
  local -Ai chars=()
  local -i i
  for ((i = 0; i < ${#1}; ++i)); do
    ((++chars["${1:i:1}"] < 2)) || return 0
  done
  return 1
}

while IFS= read -r line; do
  read -ra words <<< "$line"
  for word in "${words[@]}"; do
    containssametwice "$word" || continue 2
  done
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```